# Move branch commits to current one as uncommitted changes to working directory?

Tags: git, git-branch

Lets say that I work on `branchA`, and need to temporary commit all the uncommitted changes. So I create `branchB`, and commit everything.

After some time, I need to move all those changes back to `branchA` as uncommitted changes.

(Some changes where to files that where not previously tracked in repo)

**How can I do it? Merge + reset? Is there simple command for it?**

I could also rephrase this question as:

**How to undo git branch -b branchB; git add .; git commit; ?**

Comment: What's the problem with having a commit in the branch history?

Comment: Why can't you simply reset branchB, then stash the changes and apply the stash to branchA?

Comment: Or just cherry-pick the commit from branchB...

Comment: Can I reset whole branch as opposed to particular commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are going to throw `branchB` away, I would suggest doing `git merge branchB --squash --no-commit`. The `--no-commit` option makes sure the changes are just applied to your working directory, as opposed to committed. The `--squash` option prevents the commit that you eventually do from being a merge commit. The reason I suggest using that option is that it is not a good idea to do anything besides the merge itself in a merge commit, and it seems like you want to do some more work locally before doing a "real" commit. Plus, this prevents your temp commit on `branchB` from showing up in your history.

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't dealing with a large number of files, just check out the individual files from the other branch:

```
git checkout branchB <filename1>
git checkout branchB <filename2>
```

This brings in the files as they are at the head of the other branch.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for `cherry-pick --no-commit`:

```
git checkout branchA
git cherry-pick branchB --no-commit
```

In the above I assume all is in a single commit, but you can extend that to a sequence of cherry-picks.

See the [cherry-pick reference](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) for more info